# Using systemd, how can I identify cold boot vs reboot in a service?

Tags: linux, debian, startup, systemd

I am trying to execute a systemd service on Debian. However, I need the logic to vary based on whether it is booting up 'cold', or from a restart.

I currently have a `run-application.service` which looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run application

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/run-application

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

I want the program to be called on every boot, but the internal logic needs to be modified in the case of a reboot. What is the easiest/best way of achieving this?

Comment: i'd try creating a couple of scripts that write to a file in /tmp   set one to run at runlevel 6 ( reboot ) and one to run at runlevel 0 ( halt ) ave them output a file /tmp/lastboot.txt   then your script can read the file and know what happened.  you will need to take into account what happens if the machine is hard powered off and other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General Foch is right. Create a new systemd service, which is wanted by reboot.target, and leaves a 'mark' somewhere on the filesystem, which can get picked up on reboot. I wouldn't recommend putting it in /tmp, as the cleaning of /tmp is done by a upstart script everytime /tmp is mounted - practically, that means at every boot. I would put it in a directory that you know will persist. That way, you can know if you have come from a reboot, and you can reasonably assume that any other time you are booting that it is 'cold'. This will account for situations such as the machine losing power, etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt! This is perfect